# DNS hosting management tool

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I'm looking for a company who can manange my DNS records.
I would like a company who support wildcard DNS as well.

Comment: Shopping questions aren't allowed here. Plus a quick Google for "Secondary DNS Service" will return a thousand companies which provide this service.

Answer (score 1):

At the previous company I worked for we used [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com). They have a pretty simple web interface that gives you complete control of DNS that even mangement was able to figure out and use :)

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at www.mydomain.com.